# Js won't work if I want to add more code

Tags: javascript, html, jsfiddle

I don't know why my code will stop work if i add a if statment to my last function `var checkAnswer = function()`. If i delete the statment the code will work again fine. What's the problem with it? It's kinda wierd and I don't get it.

```js
Array.prototype.random = function(length) {
  return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * length)];
};

var country = [{
    name: "romaniei",
    capital: "bucuresti"
  }, {
    name: "bulgariei",
    capital: "sofia"
  }],
  questions = [
    "What is the capital of ",
    " is the capital of what country?"
  ]

document.querySelector('input').onclick = function() {
  var q,
    chosen_country = country.random(country.length),
    chosen_question = questions.random(questions.length);

  if (chosen_question == questions[0]) {
    q = chosen_question + chosen_country.name + "?";
  } else if (chosen_question == questions[1]) {
    q = chosen_country.capital + chosen_question;
  }

  document.querySelector('#que').innerHTML = q;
}

var checkAnswer = function() {
  var answer = document.myform.answ.value;
  if () {}
}
```

```html
<form name="myform">
  <input type="button" value="Generate question">
  <div id="que">Intrebare:</div>
  <input type="text" id="answ">
  <input type="button" value="ok">
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`if () {}` isn't a valid `if` statement - the condition body has to be an expression.

Source: [ECMAScript 5 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5)

For example, any of these are valid:

```
if (true) {}
if (1 < 2) {}
if("") {}
```

Comment: In plain words: add something in the round brackets.

Comment: Ok, I kinda understand now. But, why the rest of the code will fail if I don't put a condition in the if statment? The last function is not part of the other function to proces myform. Tha's why I don't understant why all the code depends if the if statment has a condition.

Comment: The JavaScript engine has to parse your code before it can execute any of it. The malformed statement causes the parser to throw a `SyntaxError`, which stops further parsing. If your code can't be parsed, it can't be executed.